# Rewrite subdomain as subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

We have a Ubuntu server with Apache which serves all of our web apps using subdomains. I now have a requirement to serve an app using a subfolder.

All current apps are served as follows:
subdomain.domain.com

I am trying to serve the new app as follows:
domain.com/subfolder

I have tried various htaccess and virtual host configs using answers I have found on SO with no success.

This is all very new to me so apologies if I am a bit vague.
Any guidance on the best way to go about this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```